# Pronunciation of "catch"

Tags: differences, pronunciation, dialects, vowels

I was curious about the different pronunciations of the word *catch*; more specifically, the difference between /kætʃ/ and /kɛtʃ/.

The Oxford dictionary lists both pronunciations as correct; is this difference regional? How did it come about?

Comment: Yes, it's regional. This same difference applies to how one pronounces *cat* (some pronounce it *ket*). I'm sure someone will come along with good citations momentarily. Consider changing your title, though, since the heart of your question is the pronunciation of short 'a' (/æ/) as short 'e' (/ɛ/) – *catch* is just one example.

Comment: There are also accents where *bag* and *beg* seem much alike to those not used to that accent.  Plus everybody says that vowel of *any* like the one in *get*.

Comment: @Zairja: this isn't what *Oxford* dictionary is saying. New Zealanders pronounce ***all*** instances of /æ/ like /ɛ/, but they pronounce ***all*** instances of /ɛ/ like /ɪ/, and ***all*** instances of /ɪ/ ... This is called a *chain shift*, and it's not what the dictionary is talking about. What the *Cambridge*, *Merriam-Webster*, and *Oxford* dictionaries all say is that for some Americans, *catch* is pronounced with a short e, and so is a homophone for *ketch*. These same Americans pronounce *batch* normally. I've heard this pronunciation, but I don't know what region it belongs to.

Comment: I've removed the comment. I wasn't aware of that fact when it comes to dictionaries' offered pronunciations. As far as the short e for *catch* in the US, I've heard it in several parts of Texas, up into the Midwest (Southern Great Lakes) and in Southern states before reaching Florida.

Answer (score 4):

I currently live in Pittsburgh and grew up in Southwestern PA, I can attest that /kɛtʃ/ is becoming somewhat common in the Western PA region (Kinda-Midland region). I also have a friend from Erie and a friend from New Jersey who both say /kɛtʃ/ instead of /kætʃ/. It's not the norm (and I hope it never becomes so), but it does seem more popular now than I ever remember.

Comment: I submit in evidence Perry Como's 1957 recording of *Catch a Falling Star*, which used /kɛtʃ/ without arousing anyone's ire. An awful lot of speakers use /kɛtʃ/ and /kætʃ/ interchangeably without realising they're doing it; they'll use /kætʃ/ in *Catch this!* and /kɛtʃ/ in *Didja catch it?* in almost the same breath.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's regional. This same difference applies to how one pronounces *cat* (some pronounce it *ket*). New Zealanders pronounce all instances of `/æ/` like `/ɛ/`, but they pronounce all instances of `/ɛ/` like `/ɪ/`, and all instances of `/ɪ/` ... This is called a *chain shift*. What the Cambridge, Merriam-Webster, and Oxford dictionaries all say is that for some Americans, *catch* is pronounced with a *short e*, and so is a homophone for *ketch*. These same Americans pronounce *batch* normally.

In the US, I've heard it in several parts of Texas, up into the Midwest (Southern Great Lakes) and in Southern states before reaching Florida.